# JavaScript для кастомного сохранения загруженной страницы

Tags: javascript, dom

Скажем есть сайт, в котором информация разбита на страницы с полезным текстом. Вокруг страницы с текстом много ненужной рекламы, которую я не хотел бы сохранять. Я открываю ДОМ-модель веб-странички и удаляю ненужные мне блоки с рекламой, оставляя только нужный текст. Затем сохраняю страничку. Подумал, может можно этот процесс автоматизировать скриптом. Структура любой страницы на сайте известна(каждый нужный и ненужный мне блоки имеют свои #id), была мысль создать функцию на JavaScript для автоматизации рутинной работы. Как вариант, можно вызывать её руками в инструменте разработчика веб-браузера после того как загрузилась нужная страница. Эта функция реорганизует DOM-элементы (где нужно удаляя), а затем я просто сохраняю полученный DOM.
Подскажите, можно ли осуществить такую идею и если да, то где копать. Спасибо

Comment: Можно создать массив, скажем todel и писать туда ид, теги или классы,
примерно как в jquery:

    var todel = new Array();
    var tode = ['#banner', '.banner', 'span', 'h4', '#slider'];

Далее приходимся циклом по каждому элементу массива, по первой букве определяем тег или ид или класс, далее уже убираем из DOM. Вот тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144635/ очень подробно рассматривается работа с дом.


Comment: У меня есть скрипт который должен работать с загруженным DOM, как можно привязать скрипт к DOM, и запустить его. Вот это можно считать моим главным вопросом. Простой вызов $('body').remove(); можно ввести в watch expression (проверял), но это не вариант.

Comment: В адресной строке javascript:ваш_код ?

Comment: Под "ваш_код" я понимаю вызов моей конкретной функции. А как дать понять браузеру где искать реализацию этой функции, т.е. как подгрузить в браузер мой скрипт(вместе с внешней html-страничкой)
Помогите разобраться до конца.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в комментариях вам уже ответили. Не хватает только способа вызвать написанный код "по кнопке". Способ называется [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), обрамляете ваш код в:

```
javascript:{тут ваш код};void(0);
```

...и либо вставляете в адресную строку, либо сохраняете в закладке (bookmark).